# Ancoragem com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei uma ancoragem scroll com jquery porém só funciona na mesma página, como faço para funcionar com páginas diferentes?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
    });
  });
```

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "só funciona na mesma página"? O arquivo desse código é carregado em todas as páginas?

Comment: Coloquei o código no arquivo footer dentro de um <script> e com as outras páginas eu "puxo" o arquivo footer. (É apenas um modo que tenho de deixar mais organizado, mas é como se todos os arquivos fossem apenas 1). Na tela inicial, eu clico em sobre ou fale conosco e dá uns scroll para cada um, se eu clico na página "notícias"(que é uma página diferente da inicial) e clicar em "sobre" eu quero que ele retorne para a página inicial e dê o scroll para o local onde se encontra o sobre.

Comment: o preventDefault(); ele previne o comportamento default do <a>, por isso eu não consigo retornar para a minha página inicial com ele. Preciso que quando eu estiver em outra página, a tag <a> tenha o comportamento default e depois o script da âncoragem funcione normalmente.